# Unexpected result of matrix multiplication in R

Tags: r

R program does not return the expected matrix multiplication

```
    a<- c(0,1,1,0)
    A<- matrix(a,2,2)
    B<- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
    A*B
```

gives final answer as `matrix(c(0,2,3,0), ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)`:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    3    0
```

but the actual answer should be `matrix(c(3,4,1,2), ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)`

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    1    2
```

Comment: What you are doing is element wise multiplication (`c(A) * c(B)`). Try `A %*% B` to multiply matrices. See `?"%*%"`.

Comment: the process follows a11*b11 ie element to element multiplication and not the routine matrix multiplication method as we know... I use the Ri386 3.1.0 with R studio.

Comment: @RoshanD'Almeida When I write `*` I invariably mean element-wise multiplication. Some languages with a matrix orientation divert from that convention, e.g. Matlab. Hence I wouldn't assume anything was "routine" without checking the help: `?"*"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `%*%` or `crossprod` for matrix multiplication

```
> A %*% B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    1    2

> crossprod(A, B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    1    2
```

Note that the result is a 2x2 matrix, if you want a vector as in your example, then use `matrix(crossprod(A, B), ncol=1)`